# How to stop amplify PubSub to publish message after regaining internet connection?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, aws-iot

I am using amplify PubSub with react. This react app has a button and clicking on it publishes a messages to Aws Iot. But if the user clicks without internet connection amplify queue this request for some time and publishes message when internet connection regains. How can I stop this behaviour. I don't want it to retry/queue message publish requests.